# How determine if a TestCase failed in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, testing, python-3.4

In [Chapter 20](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch20.html) of Harry Percival's Test-Driven Development with Python, there is a function to determine whether or not a TestCase has failed so it can take a screenshot:

```
# StaticLiveServerTestCase is a descendant of unittest.TestCase
class FunctionalTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        if self._test_has_failed():
            # ... snipped for brevity
        self.browser.quit()
        super().tearDown()


    def _test_has_failed(self):
        for method, error in self._outcome.errors:
            if error:
                return True
        return False
```

This `_outcome` property is implemented on the TestCase class in Python 3.4, but not in Python 2.7. Is there some way I can determine whether or not a TestCase had an error in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2.7, you can use [self._resultForDoCleanups](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/unittest/case.py#L303) which is an instance of [unittest.result.TestResult](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/unittest/result.py#L26). Be sure to check both `self._resultForDoCleanups.errors` and `self._resultForDoCleanups.failures`:

```
def _test_has_failed(self):
    for method, error in self._resultForDoCleanups.errors:
        if error:
            return True
    for method, failure in self._resultForDoCleanups.failures:
        if failure:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: In 2.7, I see a `self._resultForDoCleanups`, but it has no `errors` or `failures` attributes?

Comment: ... because I am running my tests under pytest... :( :(